Squish | Unable to launch cmd .exe
I am trying to automate command prompt of external device and explorer.exe.But squish is not able to launch it.Please provide method or code to do so.
I have tried setting its location in AUT settings and I have run it on external device as I use to run QT application.

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the checklist. Also, we don't generally provide tutorials or example code based on generic questions. Right now your question is quite unclear, as we don't know what you're actually doing. Please explain what procedure you've been following, the expected result and what you actually get (including error messages or any possible debug output).

Automating Windows's File Explorer is tricky because of its special (potential (non) multi-process) nature that makes it difficult to even hook it up with Squish GUI Tester. It is better to first know why you want to automate File Explorer at all. Can you explain?
And automating cmd.exe/console windows is not a prime goal of Squish GUI Tester, and mostly comes down to automating it like a black box, sending mouse clicks and key presses into it. Same here though, why do you want to do it? Can you explain the problem, not what you think is the solution to the problem?
